# How to use updated state value above render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I think it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am stuck to find an answer . Actually , I am trying to access updated state value in class function above render function but I am not getting updated value . when I console value in render function I got updated value  . Could someone please help me how to access updated value .

Thanks

**Code**

```
fetchAgents = e => {
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value
  });
};

fetchFilteredInventories = e => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/reports/agents/?branch=${this.state.value}`)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        agents: response.data
      });
    });
};
```

when I try to access updated state value in `fetchFilteredInventories` I am getting null value . Could someone help me to achieve my goal

Comment: Please show us your entire component code. So we can find the problem.

Comment: fetchFilteredInventories is a function, not state. ``agents`` is the state object you are looking for.

Comment: please provide the code of whole component.

Comment: did you try with  e.target.value instead of this.state.value

Comment: can you show from where are you calling fetchedFilteredInventories?

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous. When you console.log after setState, the state is not changed yet, it is in the process of changing. Try this

```
this.setState({
 value : e.target.value
 },()=>console.log(value));
```

You will see the value is updated. setState allows a callback function as arguement. So use the callback function to use the updated state value.

Read the docs for further info: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are calling your `fetchFilteredInventories` function.
After a state update in a React component certain lifecycle hooks get called, such as `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate`. you can read about them in React docs here [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).
Make sure you are calling your API call function at the right moment.
If you can, put your whole component code here for better answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try `This`

```
axios.get(`/api/reports/agents/?branch=${this.state.value}`).then(function(response) {
       this.setState({
            agents: response.data
          });
    }.bind(this));
```